# How to change SYSIN and SYSOUT (curses mode) for a background process to another terminal session (screen utility)?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnu-screen, ncurses

I currently run an background process started by a deamon process. It has no terminal and works fine as it doesn't have any screen i/o. It is started via a shell script which I can change. The shell script inherit the daemon's environment, set up additional environment variables and finally starts the program via `exec $PROG arg1 "arg 2" 1>&2`.

For running this in "debug mode" screen i/o is necessary (curses mode).

What I've tried so far:

- `exec screen -dmS FIXME $PROG arg1 "arg 2"` results in a not starting program with the error message "invalid file descriptor"
- `exec $PROG arg1 "arg 2" 1>/dev/pts/5` results in a starting program, all output can be seen on /dev/pts/5, of course input isn't possible
- `exec $PROG arg1 "arg 2" 1>/dev/pts/5 <namedpipe` results in a starting program, all output can be seen on /dev/pts/5, takes input via `echo stuff > namedpipe` from another session but this cannot be used as all function keys needs to be usable.

The "obvious" solution I thought of (but got not working):

- start a screen in another console `screen -dmS "FIXME"`
- let the background process use this screen session via `exec screen -S "FIXME" -X stuff "$PROG arg1 \"arg 2\"
  "` (newline is needed, it emulates pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key)
- attach to the screen via `screen -r "FIXME"` (reattaching works)

Problem here:
This only sends the single command to the session, which doesn't work as the complete environment is missing (starting with the current directory, going on with all environment vars). [Edit: posted a possible solution *hack* as answer (the original question is still unanswered)]

Question: Is it possible to start the background process via screen utility? (Best option would be if the new screen session is started from the background process [problem here: this process has no console at all] and to simply reattach from another window.

If this isn't possible: Are there any other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't answer the original question but likely works in most cases:

- store everything from the environment that looks important to a temporary file
- send the following commands to screen: change to directory, source the temporary file, remove the temporary file, start the program

Code:

```
   rm some_env.$$
   for e in $(env | grep "PATH\|WHATEVERISIMPORTANT")
   do 
      echo "$e" >> some_env.$$
   done
   exec screen -S "FIXME" -X stuff "cls
cd $(pwd)
. some_env.$$
rm . some_env.$$
$PROG arg1 \"arg 2\"
"
```